# Element A always under element B regardless of z-index value

Tags: css

On [my page](http://goo.gl/cTFN8i) when hovering the green cart icon (top right of the page) there's a popup appearing below it, please also check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDXYr.jpg).

For some reason the big slider below the header (Revolution Slider) is ALWAYS above the bottom of this popup, no matter the z-index value of the popup. So if I set z-index of 999999999999, the slider will STILL be above it. As a result I can't slick on the buttons at the bottom of the popup.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I can't access to your page. Also it's better if you put your code in a working example.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and CSS. I'm pretty sure an ancestor element is affecting the `z-index` of some or your elements and the fix will be as simple as setting the `z-index` on the proper ancestor element(s).

Comment: @hungerstar: you were right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body.home #header {
 z-index: 10;
}
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Worked, thanks! I had to use a higher value than 10 but that was the answer.